# Parse RSS Feeds or Websites Source Code

Tags: c#, parsing, web, rss, feed

I would like to make an app in C#, where to generate some graphics about football teams, for the most important championships.
Ex: FC Barcelona, or Real Madrid... in Primera Division...

For this, I need the last updated data, from internet, about teams like, name of team, points, ranking...

Which is the most common way to do this?

1. Do I have to find a RSS Feed for this? Do you have any information about this?
2. Do I have to find a website and from there to parse its source code?

Comment: Have you tried [google](https://www.google.de/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=6GUJWs7rKYXH8AeQ3K-QCQ&gws_rd=ssl) yet?

Answer (score 0):

If you could find the RSS feed for the information you want, that would be the best solution.

Otherwise, You could use the HTML Agility Pack, http://html-agility-pack.net/ (also available on NuGet). This makes it really easy to parse out relevant content from a messy html-page. You can (with some creative coding) write selectors that targets the content you want, on a dynamic site where the structure might change a bit. Really handy to get content of the web.